# My audio dataset shape is various, so it raised error dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, speech-recognition

I'm trying to implement speech recognition using CNN with other dataset from TensorFlow website here :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio

When I run the code to examine some audio waveforms using this code :

```
rows = 3
cols = 3
n = rows*cols
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 12))
for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds.take(n)):
  r = i // cols
  c = i % cols
  ax = axes[r][c]
  ax.plot(audio.numpy())
  ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, 0.2))
  label = label.numpy().decode('utf-8')
  ax.set_title(label)
  print(audio)
plt.show()
```

The TensorFlow tutorial output is :

```
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.0000000e+00 -3.0517578e-05 -3.0517578e-05 ...  1.2207031e-04
  1.2207031e-04 -3.0517578e-05], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-3.0517578e-05 -1.2207031e-04  1.5258789e-04 ... -9.1552734e-05
 -1.5258789e-04  6.1035156e-05], shape=(15019,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.          0.          0.         ... -0.00128174 -0.00109863
 -0.00073242], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.0000000e+00  3.0517578e-05  0.0000000e+00 ... -6.1035156e-05
 -3.0517578e-05  3.0517578e-05], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-1.2207031e-04 -1.2207031e-04 -1.5258789e-04 ... -3.0517578e-05
 -2.4414062e-04 -2.1362305e-04], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.00091553 -0.00094604 -0.00091553 ...  0.00689697  0.00665283
  0.00753784], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 3.0517578e-05  6.1035156e-05  6.1035156e-05 ... -5.7983398e-04
  0.0000000e+00  6.7138672e-04], shape=(15019,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.00021362  0.00021362  0.00021362 ... -0.00042725 -0.0005188
 -0.00061035], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.00067139  0.00653076  0.00598145 ... -0.00708008 -0.009552
 -0.00375366], shape=(16000,), dtype=float32)
```

The shape is clearly 16000 using the **Mini Speech Command dataset** http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/mini_speech_commands.zip. But not all of them, a few have shape below 16000 but not too far. But when I run that program using **The Arabic Speech Corpus for Isolated Words** from [http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~lss/arabic/](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Elss/arabic/) the output is :

```
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.00067139  0.00045776  0.00054932 ... -0.00082397 -0.00079346
 -0.00085449], shape=(13600,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.00042725  0.00024414  0.00048828 ... -0.00015259  0.00039673
  0.00045776], shape=(15040,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 1.0070801e-03  1.0986328e-03  1.1901855e-03 ... -6.1035156e-05
 -3.0517578e-05  9.1552734e-05], shape=(8480,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.00018311 -0.00064087 -0.00094604 ...  0.00039673  0.00064087
  0.00042725], shape=(12000,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-7.6293945e-04  1.5258789e-04 -8.5449219e-04 ...  3.0517578e-05
 -6.1035156e-05 -9.1552734e-05], shape=(7360,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 9.1552734e-05  3.0517578e-05  0.0000000e+00 ... -1.2512207e-03
  2.4414062e-04  9.7656250e-04], shape=(15680,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 4.5776367e-04  4.2724609e-04  4.2724609e-04 ... -9.1552734e-05
 -1.8310547e-04 -2.1362305e-04], shape=(15840,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[ 3.0517578e-04  3.0517578e-04  2.4414062e-04 ... -2.7465820e-04
 -6.1035156e-05  6.1035156e-05], shape=(10880,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[-0.00021362 -0.00033569 -0.00048828 ...  0.00033569  0.00030518
  0.00042725], shape=(14080,), dtype=float32)
```

The shape is really vary and not even close to 16000. It cause the model do not executed properly and I think it was because of the shape of the audio itself.
Is the shape become vary because of the difference about the duration of the audio? Or because of other reason?

Because I have to add really big zero padding to every audio to iterate through norm_layer.adapt()

```
def get_spectrogram(waveform):
      # Padding for files with less than 16000 samples
      zero_padding = tf.zeros([28700] - tf.shape(waveform), dtype=tf.float32)
    
      # Concatenate audio with padding so that all audio clips will be of the 
      # same length
      waveform = tf.cast(waveform, tf.float32)
      equal_length = tf.concat([waveform, zero_padding], 0)
      spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(
          equal_length, frame_length=255, frame_step=128)
          
      spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    
      return spectrogram
```

Previously the tf.zeros([28700] is actually tf.zeros([16000]. Because if I didn't change it the error will raise on norm_layer.adapt():

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Dimension -260 must be >= 0
     [[{{node zeros}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Dimension -260 must be >= 0
     [[{{node zeros}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
```

Any revelation will be really appreciated thank you :(

Note : I have convert my audio from the Arabic speech dataset to 16KHz and 1 channel
Full code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zpAL1osxO4FS9b6__5EWEkjHHyIJ4z-S?usp=sharing

Comment: It might be worth going back over this and refining what it is your are trying to ask. If the question is _is the audio a different shape because of duration?_ then yes. `16000` would be exactly one second of audio at 16 kHz sampling rate. It would make sense for that to consistent in an example dataset. If the question is _do I have to zero pad to make the shape uniform across all audio files_ the answer is yes, however that might not be necessary if are happy to sacrifice some shortcuts in programming. Ultimately that choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge @fdcpp, so how to create the exact 16000 shape? Do you know any library or steps to preprocess it?

Comment: Either window and truncate the data or zero pad, those are the standard procedures in this situation.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am working on Arabic alphabets and I have pre-processed the dataset into 16k. But still, I have an error. Why did you choose 28700 for zero padding?